# using StandardSetController pagination working but disable previous and first button not enable when we next button or last

Tags: controller, pagination, standardsetcontroller

[image]

[image]
this is my class

```
public without sharing class TaskAssignmentDashboardController {
    public list < contact > clist {get;set;}
    Public Integer size {get;set;}
    Public Integer noOfRecords {get;set;}
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
    //Constructor memory allocate 
    public TaskAssignmentDashboardController() {
        clist = new List < contact > ();
        size = 6;
        setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
            [Select c.Phone, c.Name, c.MailingCountry, c.Email, (Select t.Id, t.WhoId, t.Subject, t.Status, t.AccountId, t.CreatedDate From Tasks t), c.Birthdate, c.AccountId From Contact c]));
        setCon.setPageSize(size);
        noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
        first();
    }
    public Boolean hasNext {
        get {
            return setCon.getHasNext();
        }
        set;
    }
    //Method to find weather previous page exists or not
    public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get {
            return setCon.getHasPrevious();
        }
        set;
    }
    public void first() {
        setCon.first();
        clist = setCon.getRecords();
    }
    //Method to show last page
    public void last() {
        setCon.last();
        clist = setCon.getRecords();
    }
    //Method to show previous page
    public void previous() {
        setCon.previous();
        clist = setCon.getRecords();
    }
    //Method to show next page
    public void next() {
        setCon.next();
        clist = setCon.getRecords();
    }
}
```

---

this is my page

```
<div class="slds-card__body">
    <apex:outputPanel id="details">
        <div style="width:100%;border:0px;">
            <apex:repeat value="{!clist}" var="con">
                <div class="ui-widget-header users">
                    <a href="/{!con.Id}" target="_blank"> {!con.Name} </a>
                    <ul id="sortable2" class="dropfalse" style="border:0px;margin-top:5px;width: 98%;background-color:steelblue;border-radius:10px;" onchange="getlist();">
                        <apex:repeat value="{!con.Tasks}" var="cnTsk">
                            <li id="{!cnTsk.Id}" class="ui-state-default assigned">
                                <div style="font-weight:bold;">{!cnTsk.Subject}</div>
                                <div style="font-weight:bold;">
                                    <apex:outputField value="{!cnTsk.CreatedDate}" />
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </apex:repeat>
        </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</div>
<div class="slds-card__footer">
    <div style="width:100%;border:0px;">
        <apex:commandButton status="fetching" reRender="frm" value="First" immediate="true" action="{!first}" disabled="{!!hasPrevious }" title="First Page" styleclass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--small" />
        <apex:commandButton status="fetching" reRender="frm" value="Previous" immediate="true" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!!hasPrevious }" title="Previous Page" styleclass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--small" />
        <apex:commandButton status="fetching" reRender="frm" value="Next" immediate="true" action="{!next}" disabled="{!!hasNext}" title="Next Page" styleclass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--small" />
        <apex:commandButton status="fetching" reRender="frm" value="Last" immediate="true" action="{!last}" disabled="{!!hasNext}" title="Last Page" styleclass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--small" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: to enable/disable buttons on action, you need to rerender them as well

Comment: i have use it. 
<apex:commandButton status="fetching" reRender="details" value="First" immediate="true" action="{!first}" disabled="{!!hasPrevious }" title="First Page" styleclass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--small" />
        <apex:commandButton status="fetching" reRender="details" value="Previous" immediate="true" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!!hasPrevious }" title="Previous Page" styleclass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--small" />

Comment: I mean you need to reRender no only section, but block with buttons as well. Wrap it to output panel, assign id to that and rerender those id on commandbuttons as well

Comment: @Thanks Kurunve. work fine... i have puzzled from last day..

Comment: @kurunve would be nice if you put this in an 'answer' so the question can be marked as answered and thus help other people with similar problems. Also you will get more credits that way ;-)

Comment: i have changed reRender "details" to "frm" that is form id name. now its work and i have edited in question and work good